# Substract half of div width with js

Tags: javascript, width, percentage

I'm new using JS and I'm having troubles with a simple action:

First `div` is 50% width

I'm looking to subtract from its width the 50% of a Second div using JS.

Would be like:

```
a_div width = 50% - ( 50% width of b_div)
```

I've tried this but it's not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#h-prev").css({'width':($(".swiper-slide-prev").innerWidth())}).css('width:'-$(".swiper-slide-prev").width() * .50);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the parent width divided by 2 and subtract the other element width divided by 2

```
var $el = $("#h-prev"),
    parentWidth = $el.parent().width(),
    otherWidth = $(".swiper-slide-prev").width(),
    newWidth =(parentWidth/2) - (otherWidth/2)

$el.width( newWidth );
```

Comment: That worked for me! But would it be possible to make it change in real time when rescaling the browser?. By now the width is set only when loading the page and it keeps static. Many thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Wrap it in `$(window).on('resize', function() { /* code here */}).resize()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if this is what you are looking for, but I've written up this demo in plain javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/tubL1qxr/2/

```
var a = document.getElementById('a'), // element a
    b = document.getElementById('b'), // element b
  h = document.getElementById('h'); // button

h.addEventListener('click', changeSize);

function changeSize() {
    a.style.width = ((window.innerWidth / 100 *50) - (b.offsetWidth /100*50)) + 'px';
}
```

You would quite obviously, have to modify it to fit your code.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the first and the second divs width, then subtracts half of the second divs width from the first div's width (which is 50% initially).

Is this what you meant:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var secondDivWidth = parseInt($('#second-div').css('width'));
  var firstDivWidth = parseInt($('#first-div').css('width')); 
  $('#first-div').css('width', firstDivWidth - secondDivWidth/2);
  
  // Example purposes only
  console.log("Width before change (50%): " + firstDivWidth);
  console.log("Width after change: " + $('#first-div').css('width'));
   
})
```

```css
#first-div {
  border: black solid 1px;
  height: 100px;
  width:50%;
}

#second-div {
  border: red solid 1px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first-div">

</div>
<div id="second-div">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors:

jQuery css() functions works in 2 ways, accept object or 2 parameters:

1) css('attr', value)

2) css({'attr':value})

So you can correct this 'width:' and put this 'width': and put in {}
Result will be following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#h-prev").css({
        'width': ($(".swiper-slide-prev").innerWidth())
    }).css({'width':- $(".swiper-slide-prev").width() * .50});
});
```

In case of giving only one parametter you can use second option and code will be following

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#h-prev").css('width', ($(".swiper-slide-prev").innerWidth())).css('width', -$(".swiper-slide-prev").width() * .50);
});
```

So now syntax is correct, and if you will put here your code with snippet I will be able to help you with functionality.